# MongoDB: How to obtain value of nested object?

Tags: mongodb, document

If the following is document

```
{ 'a': { 
        'b': ['a', 'x', 'b'],
        't': ['a', 'z', 'w', 't']
       }
}
```

I want to be able to obtain the value associated with the nested object. For example, in python, I would do `print(dict_name['a']['t'])`.

I have tried `find()` and `findOne()` on both of the commands below

```
db.my_collection.find({}, { 'a.t': 1 })
db.my_collection.find({ 'a.t': {$exists: 'true} })
```

but they haven't been returning the correct data.

How can I query for the document with `'a'` as a key, then that document,  obtain the value associated with `'t'`, expecting `['a', 'z', 'w', 't']` to be returned?

Comment: How about `db.collection.aggregate([ {$project: {"ts": "$a.t", _id: 0}} ])`

Comment: `"t" is a key for "a"`, so you create non-id entry, bad idea cos always need call whole entry. Ex : {"a":"b","val":["a","x","b"]}

Comment: @AliDehghani I get a bunch of blank objects

Comment: I guess you should filter them using the `$match`.

Comment: @AliDehghani Then how do I handle the nesting? Is that what `"$a.t"` is for? Also, what is "ts"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            '_id': '$_id',
            't': '$a.t'
        }
    }
])
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

Heres a link to **[project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)**, basically assigning your **'a.t'** array to a new value named **'t'** (this is what 't': '$a.t' pretty much means)

Comment: Although its correct but its an overkill. For each document, you unwind it to n documents and then group them again to form the document you originally had with just a few keys present. Why not just use project?

Comment: thanks for the heads up, edited the above, for some reason it wasn't working on my end doing the project only, but i may have had a typo

Answer (score 0):

How about this? :

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([{"$project":{"_id":"$_id", "t":"$a.t"}}]);
```

On this test collection

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("577ba92187630c1a06c4bcac"),
        "a" : {
                "b" : [
                        1,
                        2
                ],
                "t" : [
                        2,
                        3
                ]
        }
}
```

It gave me the following result-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577ba92187630c1a06c4bcac"), "t" : [ 2, 3 ] }
```